# ESP-Matter project fails to find library under components

Tags: c++, cmake, vscode-extensions, esp32, esp-idf

I cloned the ESP-Matter's lighting-app [example](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/tree/master/examples/lighting-app/esp32).
Then I added a few libraries under components and made sure of CMakeLists.txt, and ran the below idf.py commands

```
idf.py create-manifest --component=<name>
idf.py reconfigure
```

However, when I compile I get an error not finding the library

```
esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/main/Button.cpp:19:10: fatal error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory
```

#include "Arduino.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Even the Arduino library that I added through `ESP-IDF: Add Arduino ESP32 as ESP-IDF Component` command fails to be found and gives the above error. What could I have missed?

Here is output of build. As you can see it says Arduino is added as a component, but is giving the build error not finding Arduino.h

```
❯ idf.py build
Executing action: all (aliases: build)
Running ninja in directory /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/build
Executing "ninja all"...
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32
-- Found Python3: /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.16") found components: Interpreter
-- Project sdkconfig file /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/sdkconfig
Loading defaults file /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/sdkconfig.defaults...
warning: ENABLE_ESP32_LOCATIONCAPABILITY (defined at /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/third_party/connectedhomeip/config/esp32/components/chip/Kconfig:660) has leading or trailing whitespace in its prompt
-- App "chip-light-switch-app" version: v1.0
-- Adding linker script /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/build/esp-idf/esp_system/ld/memory.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_system/ld/esp32/sections.ld.in
-- Adding linker script /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.api.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.libgcc.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-data.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.syscalls.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-funcs.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-time.ld
-- Adding linker script /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/ld/esp32.peripherals.ld
-- Components: QRCode app_trace app_update arduino asio bootloader bootloader_support bt cbor chip cmock coap console cxx driver efuse esp-tls esp32 esp32_mbedtls esp_adc_cal esp_common esp_eth esp_event esp_gdbstub esp_hid esp_http_client esp_http_server esp_https_ota esp_https_server esp_hw_support esp_ipc esp_lcd esp_local_ctrl esp_netif esp_phy esp_pm esp_ringbuf esp_rom esp_serial_slave_link esp_system esp_timer esp_websocket_client esp_wifi espcoredump esptool_py expat fatfs freemodbus freertos hal heap idf_test ieee802154 jsmn json libsodium log lwip main mbedtls mdns mqtt newlib nghttp nvs_flash openssl openthread partition_table perfmon protobuf-c protocomm pthread sdmmc soc spi_flash spiffs tcp_transport tcpip_adapter tinyusb ulp unity usb vfs wear_levelling wifi_provisioning wpa_supplicant xtensa
-- Component paths: /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/common/QRCode /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/app_trace /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/app_update /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/components/arduino /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/asio /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bootloader /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bootloader_support /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/cbor /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/third_party/connectedhomeip/config/esp32/components/chip /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/cmock /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/coap /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/console /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/cxx /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/driver /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/efuse /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp-tls /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp32 /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/third_party/connectedhomeip/config/esp32/components/esp32_mbedtls /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_adc_cal /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_common /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_eth /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_event /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_gdbstub /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_hid /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_http_client /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_http_server /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_https_ota /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_https_server /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_ipc /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_lcd /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_local_ctrl /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_netif /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_phy /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_pm /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_ringbuf /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_serial_slave_link /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_system /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_timer /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_websocket_client /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/espcoredump /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esptool_py /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/expat /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/fatfs /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/freemodbus /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/freertos /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/hal /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/heap /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/idf_test /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/ieee802154 /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/jsmn /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/json /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/libsodium /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/log /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/lwip /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/main /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/mbedtls /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/mdns /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/mqtt /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/newlib /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/nghttp /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/nvs_flash /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/openssl /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/openthread /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/partition_table /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/perfmon /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/protobuf-c /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/protocomm /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/pthread /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/sdmmc /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/soc /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/spi_flash /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/spiffs /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/tcp_transport /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/tcpip_adapter /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/tinyusb /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/ulp /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/unity /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/usb /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/vfs /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/wear_levelling /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/wifi_provisioning /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/wpa_supplicant /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/xtensa
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/build
[309/455] Performing build step for 'chip_gn'
[0/1] Regenerating ninja files
ninja: no work to do.
[315/455] Building CXX object esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/Button.cpp.obj
FAILED: esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/Button.cpp.obj
/Users/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++ -DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE=\"mbedtls/esp_config.h\" -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/build/config -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/third_party/connectedhomeip/zzz_generated/light-switch-app -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/main/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/third_party/connectedhomeip/examples/providers -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/third_party/connectedhomeip/examples/platform/esp32 -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/build/gen/app-codegen/cpp-app -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/freertos/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions/freertos -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc/esp32 -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/. -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/private_include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/heap/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/log/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps/sntp -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/include/arch -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/soc/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/. -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/hal/esp32/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/hal/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/hal/platform_port/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include/esp32 -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32 -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/soc -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/public_compat -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp32/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/xtensa/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/xtensa/esp32/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/driver/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/driver/esp32/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_pm/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_ringbuf/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/efuse/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/efuse/esp32/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/vfs/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_event/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_netif/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_eth/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/tcpip_adapter/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/esp32/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_ipc/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/app_trace/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/esp_timer/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/src/platform/ESP32 -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/src/platform/OpenThread -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/src/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/src/lib -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/src -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/zzz_generated/app-common -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/platform/esp32 -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/third_party/nlassert/repo/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/third_party/nlio/repo/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/build/esp-idf/chip/src/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/build/esp-idf/chip/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/build/esp-idf/chip/gen/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/config/esp32 -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/config/esp32/../.. -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/common/QRCode/repo/c -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/common/osi/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/include/esp32/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/common/api/include/api -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/common/btc/profile/esp/blufi/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/common/btc/profile/esp/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/porting/nimble/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/port/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/services/ans/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/services/bas/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/services/dis/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/services/gap/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/services/gatt/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/services/ias/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/services/ipss/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/services/lls/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/services/tps/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/util/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/store/ram/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/store/config/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/porting/npl/freertos/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/esp-hci/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/nvs_flash/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/spi_flash/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/port/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/esp_crt_bundle/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/app_update/include -I/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf/components/bootloader_support/include -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Werror=all -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -ggdb -Og -fmacro-prefix-map=/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32=. -fmacro-prefix-map=/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-idf=IDF -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -fno-jump-tables -fno-tree-switch-conversion -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wno-format-security -Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -std=gnu++17 -Os -DCHIP_HAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE -DIDF_VER=\"v4.4.2\" -DESP_PLATFORM -D_POSIX_READER_WRITER_LOCKS "-DCHIP_ADDRESS_RESOLVE_IMPL_INCLUDE_HEADER=<lib/address_resolve/AddressResolve_DefaultImpl.h>" -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/Button.cpp.obj -MF esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/Button.cpp.obj.d -o esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/Button.cpp.obj -c /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/main/Button.cpp
/Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/main/Button.cpp:19:10: fatal error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Arduino.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[328/455] Building CXX object esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/__/third_party/connectedhomeip/src/app/server/CommissioningWindowManager.cpp.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I think I found something similar, and might be related to Arduino core being supported only on esp-idf 4.4 and esp-matter on 5.0.1. What esp-idf version are you using?
also, does /Users/workspace/embedded/esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/examples/light-switch-app/esp32/components/arduino include the Arduino.h file somewhere inside it? If its there, it might be something related to the CMakeLists.txt missing some requirements.